# Convergence/integrability of $f_n(x) =(2-x)^{n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, functions

> Let $f_n:[1,2] \to [0,1]$ be given by $f_n(x) =(2-x)^{n}$for all non- negative integers $n$.
>
> Let $f(x) = \lim_{ n \to \infty} f_{n}(x)$ for $1 \leq x \leq 2$. Then which of the following is true.?
>
> 1. $f$ is continuous function on $[1,2]$
> 2. $f_n$ converges uniformly to $f$ on $[1,2]$ as $n \to \infty$.
> 3. $\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{1}^{2} f_n(x)dx = \int_{1}^{2}f(x)dx$.
> 4. for any $a \in (1,2)$ we have $\lim_{n \to \infty}f_{n}^{'}(a) \neq f^{'}(a)$.

Now for $x=2$, $f_n(x) =0$ and $x=1$ $f_n(x) = 1$ for all $n$. Hence this is not uniformly convergence.

Comment: The title is vague.

Comment: Have you found $f$?

Comment: Sorry..i am just started reading ana lysis..so i dont know to find it..if you tell me how to i will do accordingly

Comment: Choose for comfort and look at $g_n:[0,1]\to[0,1]$ defined by $x\mapsto x^n$. The conclusions can easily be projected on $f_n=g_n\circ h$ for $h:[1,2]\to[0,1]$ prescribed by $x\mapsto2-x$.